# How to download files from sources using Chrome DevTools Protocol and Selenium (Python)?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools

How can I use the Chrome DevTools Protocol with Selenium (Python) to download a file from sources, similar to how it is done manually as shown in the screenshot?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. You just download the raw text/html of the page in that example. You don't need devtools